# How to scrape values from a dropdown list? ("Li") tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the countries with their rates from this page: https://www.bossrevolution.ca/en-ca. The webpage has a drop down list which shows all the countries. Once you click on the country you are redirected to a next page and on that webpage you can see the rate of the country in question. What I basically want to do is a run a code whereby I have all the countries with their rates. The only difficult thing is that for every country I'm redirected to a new webpage.

I started with step one and that is scraping all the countries from the drop down list but I have some difficulties with that. The code that I wrote:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://www.bossrevolution.ca/en-ca/services/international-calling"

req = requests.get(url)

data = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

data1 = data.find("ul")
for li in data1.find_all("li"):
    print(li.text, end=" ")
```

My output:

```
 




                                        Services
                                    






                                                International Calling
                                            






                                                International Mobile Top Up
                                            


 




                                                International Calling
                                            
 




                                                International Mobile Top Up
                                            
 




                                                Support
                                            
 

                                                My Account
```

I'm trying to get the countries seen on the picture?

[All countries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUo3w.png)

Could someone please help an intern out? It would help me a lot with a achieving a good grade :)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded via JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see them. To get all rates for all countries in Json format you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests

country_list = "https://www.bossrevolution.com/en-us/rates/ajax/countries_list"
rates_api = "https://www.bossrevolution.com/en-us/rates/ajax/data/{}"

countries = requests.get(country_list).json()

for c in countries:
    url = rates_api.format(c[0])
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    # pretty print the returned data:
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "CountryId": "AF",
    "CountryName": "Afghanistan",
    "Amount": "",
    "Page": 2,
    "Rates": {
        "CountryCode": "AF",
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "dest": [
            {
                "name": "Afghanistan",
                "Currency": null,
                "rate": "0.25"
            },
            {
                "name": "Afghanistan Cellular",
                "Currency": null,
                "rate": "0.117"
            },
            {
                "name": "Afghanistan Cellular-Roshan",
                "Currency": null,
                "rate": "0.135"
            }
        ],
        "IsdCode": null
    },
    "IsRatesFound": true,
    "DestinationRates": [
        {
            "name": "Afghanistan",
            "Currency": null,
            "rate": "0.25"
        },
        {
            "name": "Afghanistan Cellular",
            "Currency": null,
            "rate": "0.117"
        },
        {
            "name": "Afghanistan Cellular-Roshan",
            "Currency": null,
            "rate": "0.135"
        }
    ],
    "LastUpdatedAt": "/Date(1668229257000)/"
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    "CountryId": "AL",
    "CountryName": "Albania",
    "Amount": "",
    "Page": 2,
    "Rates": {
        "CountryCode": "AL",
        "name": "Albania",
        "dest": [
            {
                "name": "Albania",
                "Currency": null,
                "rate": "0.15"
            },
            {
                "name": "Albania Cellular",
                "Currency": null,
                "rate": "0.359"
            },
            {
                "name": "Albania,Tirana",
                "Currency": null,
                "rate": "0.161"
            }
        ],
        "IsdCode": null
    },
    "IsRatesFound": true,
    "DestinationRates": [
        {
            "name": "Albania",
            "Currency": null,
            "rate": "0.15"
        },
        {
            "name": "Albania Cellular",
            "Currency": null,
            "rate": "0.359"
        },
        {
            "name": "Albania,Tirana",
            "Currency": null,
            "rate": "0.161"
        }
    ],
    "LastUpdatedAt": "/Date(1668229257000)/"
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    "CountryId": "DZ",
    "CountryName": "Algeria",
    "Amount": "",
    "Page": 2,
    "Rates": {
        "CountryCode": "DZ",
        "name": "Algeria",
        "dest": [
            {
                "name": "Algeria",
                "Currency": null,
                "rate": "0.083"
            },
            {
                "name": "Algeria Cellular",
                "Currency": null,
                "rate": "0.625"
            }
        ],
        "IsdCode": null
    },
    "IsRatesFound": true,
    "DestinationRates": [
        {
            "name": "Algeria",
            "Currency": null,
            "rate": "0.083"
        },
        {
            "name": "Algeria Cellular",
            "Currency": null,
            "rate": "0.625"
        }
    ],
    "LastUpdatedAt": "/Date(1668229257000)/"
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I've been struggling with this for a long time so I'm so happy you helped me. I really appreciate it. Thank you once again.

Comment: If I want to read the output in an easy readable way you can normally use prettify. What can I use for the code you just sent to me? My goal is namely to export the data to an excell sheet where I can easily compare it to other rates.

Comment: @Demi You can use for example `pandas`, create a dataframe from necessary data and save it as CSV or XLS.

Comment: Let's say I want to run the code you gave me for this website: www.rebtel.com in which I again want to scrape the countries with its currencies. Is the only thing that needs to be changed the urls or am I missing out on something?

Comment: I for example have this now: import json
import requests

country_list = "https://www.rebtel.com/en/rates/countrieslist"
rates_api = "https://www.rebtel.com/en/rates/"

countries = requests.get(country_list).json()

for c in countries:
    url = rates_api.format(c[0])
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    # pretty print the returned data:
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
    print("-" * 80)

Comment: @Demi No, each server is unique - for each site you need to have different code.